# Email updates for filter delayed by several hours

Tags: bug, email-notification, tag-filters

I'm using a filter (https://stackexchange.com/filters/305027/sam#) to keep track of new questions within my area of interest. I have email updates enabled for every 15 minutes.

[image]

Since a couple of days, these email only come very sporadically. For example today  I got an update that summarises questions posted several hours apart and sent about 12 hours after the oldest question was posted.

[image]

**Update:** After getting this email at 9:49 (local time), several more copies of the exact same mail arrived at 10:52 and 12:12 (both also local time)

Comment: I see weird results in the filter pages. I posted a bug question 11 hrs ago.

Comment: @teylyn mmm, maybe some weird stuff going on behind the scenes. In my case, I can see new questions in the filter, just the emails seem to be delayed.